# Android call method on object in ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, object, methods, arraylist

in my project I fill an ArrayList with different objects.

```
private List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
...
objectList.add(StudentObject);
objectList.add(ManagerObject);
objectList.add(AnimalObject);
```

Each of my object-class contains a method called getType(){} which returns an int value. Now I want to call this method on an object in the list.

```
objectList.get(i).getType();
```

This dosen't work, maybe because the list expected an object and not every object-class have the method getType(); ?

But how can I avoid this problem and call the method on the objects in the list?

Comment: `Each of my object-class contains a method called getType(){}`, no, because your arraylist is declared to contain `Object`s, which don't have such method. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve what you are asking, then make it an `ArrayList` of your own object that contains that method.

```
public abstract class MyTypeObject extends Object
{
   abstract int getType();
}

public class MyObject1 extends MyTypeObject
{
   private int type = 201; 

   int getType()
   {
       return type;
   }   
}
```

Then, instead of passing along Objects, pass along a MyTypeObject.  This forces any MyTypeObject to have the getType() method.  You can then assign your ArrayList like this instead.

```
private List<MyTypeObject> objectList = new ArrayList<MyTypeObject>();
```

and then you can guarantee that it has your getType() method and you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` does not contain `getType` you need to cast it to the type of object it is.

before you cast you first you need to check if the object is on a certain type so you dont get crashes

example

```
if(objectList.get(i) instanceof StudentObject){
    StudentObject student = (StudentObject)objectList.get(i)
    student.getType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface or superclass that defines `getType()` and have each of your classes implement or inherit from that.

Example:

```
public interface Typed {
    public int getType();
}

public class Student implements Typed {
    public int getType() {
        // code here
    }
}

// similar definitions for other classes

// later in some other code...
List<Typed> list = new ArrayList<Typed>();
list.add(new Student());
// add other objects...

// then this...
int typei = list.get(i).getType();

// or maybe this...
for (Typed object : list) {
    int type = object.getType();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Object` in Java does not have the `getType` method. If all of the objects you're inserting into this list have the method `getType`, consider using an [`Interface`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29). Then, instead of inserting `Objects` into your List, you can insert the the Interface.

For example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public int getType();
}
```

Have each of your classes implement this interface.

```
public class StudentObject implements MyInterface {
    ...
    @Override
    public int getType() {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, in your list:

```
private List<MyInterface> objectList = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
...
objectList.add(StudentObject);
objectList.add(ManagerObject);
objectList.add(AnimalObject);
```

Now, each thing that is added from `objectList` must be of type `MyInterface`. Similarly, everything read from `objectList` will be of type `MyInterface` and you will be able to call `getType`.

The other way of doing this would be casting things you get out of your `objectList`.